# Ruby on Rails - has_one relation, how to check if it has an existing association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-one

I have a simple problem, related to associations.
I have a model for book, that has_one reservation.
Reservation belongs_to book.

I want to make sure in the create method of reservations controller that a book is not reserved already when a reservation is made. In other words, I need to check if any other reservation exists for that book. How do i do that?

EDIT:
Aaaand i made it, thanks everyone for the tips, learned some new stuff. When i tried offered solutions, I got no_method errors, or nil_class etc. That got me thinking, that the objects I'm trying to work on simply don't exist. Krule gave me the idea to use book.find, so i tried working with that.
Ultimately i got it working with:

```
book=Book.find_by_id(reservation_params[:book_id])
unless book.is_reserved?
```

Thanks everybody for your anwsers, I know it's basic stuff but i learned a lot. Cheers!

Comment: Hey, i tried book.reservation.any? and similar constructs. I think the problem is, object Book is not present in the reservations controller. The book id is passed as a parameter from a different controller.

Comment: Better edit the question to add that data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#app/models/book.rb

def is_reserved?
  !self.reservation.nil?
end

# Somewhere else
book = Book.find(id)
book.is_reserved?
```

Comment: Now getting error: undefined local variable or method `id' for #<ReservationsController:0x000000050ef3f8>

I think the books are not visible in the reservations controller. The book id is passed from different controller as a parameter.

Comment: You should use an actual book id **variable** instead of just writing id without instantiating it as variable. Something along the lines of `id = params[:id]` in controller or numeric value representing it should do the trick.

Answer (score 10):

How about:

`self.reservation.present?`

This should return true if an association exists.

Answer (score 7):

Little bit performance gain can be obtained if you use

```rb
#app/models/book.rb
def is_reserved?
  Reservation.exists?(book_id: id)
end

#somewhere else
book = Book.find(id)
book.is_reserved?
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply, use:

```
# book = Book.first
book.reservation.nil?   # returns true if no reservation
                        # is associated with this book
```

Comment: It give me error: undefined local variable or method `book' for #<ReservationsController:0x0000000546a258>